# Embed GTK look and feel in runnable jar

Tags: swing, executable-jar, look-and-feel

I have a little problem. I made an application which has to use the GTK Look and Feel. But the user will be able to launch the application from windows OS where this LaF doesn't exist...
Can anyone tell me whether it's possible to embed GTK LaF in my runnable jar and load it at runtime?

Thanks a lot!

Regards,

Paranoia25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to properly run GTK look and feel on other OS (even if you succeed at extracting it from your OS standard java libraries) due to some native features usage. That is true for all native LaF's - windows/macos/GTK and some others.

I would suggest you to look into some cross-platform LaFs for Swing and use them instead of native one if you are going to create a good-looking cross-platform application based on Swing.